# Why my link is not working on Asp.Net Master Page?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, webforms, master-pages

I have a given two link on side navbar. but It's not working why?

Here is my code:

**Admin.Master**

```
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width: 200px; padding-top: 50px;" id="mySidebar">
        <button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()">Close &times;</button>
        <a href="CreateUser.aspx" id="linkCreateUser" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</a>
        <a href="AdminSecurity.aspx" id="linkSecurity" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
        <%--<a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>--%>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-main" style="margin-left: 200px; padding-top: 50px;">

        <div class="w3-container">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkCreateUser" runat="server" PostBackUrl="https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl" CssClass="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Create User hyper" NavigateUrl="CreateUser.aspx" CssClass="w3-bar-item w3-button" ></asp:HyperLink>
<a href="AdminSecurity.aspx" runat="server" id="linkSecurity" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
```

It appears on chrome browser for above code

**Chrome browser**

```
 <a id="HyperLink1" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="CreateUser.aspx">Create User hyper</a>
 <a id="linkCreateUser" class="w3-bar-item w3-button active" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$linkCreateUser", "", false, "", "https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl", false, true))'>Create User</a>
 <a href="AdminSecurity.aspx" id="linkSecurity" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
```

**Jquery Click event**

```
$('.w3-sidebar a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // it's not working because of this. But how can I set class = active for clicking link?
    $('.w3-sidebar a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: You have missed `runat="server" ` on anchor tag

Comment: Which kind you mean "not working" (throwing 404 or something error)? Provide more details (also seems that your page primarily uses webforms ASPX instead of MVC).

Comment: @Tetsuyayamamoto no response. no error. no reload

Comment: @Curiousdev I tried that too

Comment: is your `CreateUser.aspx` and `AdminSecurity.aspx` both page in same directory as this current page ?

Comment: @Curiousdev yes both are in same directory. If not so, It has to show 404 page not found exception right?

Comment: Probably you are right i just have doubts so i asked anyways you can use `LinkButton` as well instead `anchor` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try using asp.net control either it works or no like:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkCreateUser" runat="server" PostBackUrl="CreateUser.aspx" CssClass="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HyperLink ID="linkCreateUser" runat="server" Text="Create User" NavigateUrl="CreateUser.aspx" CssClass="w3-bar-item w3-button" ></asp:HyperLink>
```

if still not working please share final html of anchor tag by inspect element which is showing on web page?

Comment: you anchor tag is not firing click event? or its not going to right page?

Comment: yes. it's not responding any thing. no error message,nothing

Comment: click event is not firing. even it is not going to server also. I create a link and redirect from server. That too not working

Comment: check onclick event on tag is working?
    <a onclick="alert('This is test')">Create User</a>
if working then you can use window.location.href to redirect to that page..its for the time solution not permanent.

Comment: try it by changing the position of preventDefault. and you are using this code only to check clicked event?

Answer (score 0):

if your pages are in root of the project just put "/" before your internal link:

```
<a href="/CreateUser.aspx" id="linkCreateUser" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</a>

<a href="/AdminSecurity.aspx" id="linkSecurity" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
```

Comment: where is the master page exactly in the your project, Is it in the root?